# Why doesn't gunicorn write log to reopened file while rotating a log file?

Tags: gunicorn, logrotate

My test scenario is as below.

1. Run `gunicorn`

   - `$ gunicorn main:app --conf=./settings/gunicorn/gunicorn.py`
2. Remove `access.log` file
3. Send a signal `USR1` to let `gunicorn` reopen new log `access.log` file.

   - `kill -USR1 $(cat ./data/pid/gunicorn.pid)`
4. `gunicorn` write to the new `access.log` file.

Step 1~3 seems working as expected, creating a new `access.log` file after `gunicorn` receives `USR1` signal.

However, gunicorn doesn't write log anymore to the new log file.

```
# gunicorn.py (config)
import multiprocessing

worker_class = 'uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker'
workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
pidfile = './data/pid/gunicorn.pid'
bind = 'unix:./data/socket/auth.sock'
accesslog = './data/log/gunicorn/access.log'
errorlog = './data/log/gunicorn/error.log'
```

Comment: Is this problem solved?

Comment: @Ykh, No It's not, I just use `copytruncate` option for logrotate.

Comment: I add a new issue for uvicorn,hope anyone can find the reason. [issue here](https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/issues/896)

Comment: `copytruncate` works like a charm! thank you !

Comment: but `copytruncate ` has the risk of lost log record